# How is looking process of making HDR movie?

Tags: software, hardware, hdr

I'm going to work with conversion from SDR to HDR content. So I am looking for material where I can compare 2 version of the same movie, e.g. "A star is born" in HDR and in SDR.

I know that HDR by means is "higher dynamic range", "wider color space", "higher bit depth" and 4k (from https://video.stackexchange.com/a/21678/26522). But I'm little confused, how these movies are assembled.

Questions:

1. Do the operator has a couple of cameras with different exposure settings? E.g. first camera with 1/120s, second 1/60s and third 1/30s?
2. Or maybe movie is recorded in RAW format, and I can get material 1/120, 1/60 and 1/30 from RAW format?
3. Who is mearging these material? I'm pretty sure, that software will do that, but this software can be controlled - do you know which software do they use? Adobe Premiere?
4. Do I need camera with recording material in 2020 colorspace to get HDR movie?

--edit--

5. Is this camera solves all of my questions: Alexa SXT (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arri_Alexa#Alexa_SXT) ?

Answer (score 0):

After some searching I have get this link: https://photography.tutsplus.com/tutorials/what-is-hdr-video-3-ways-to-create-high-dynamic-range-video--cms-25884

According to this link and RED company's cameras:

1. No there are now multiple cameras which are recording the same scene
2. These special cameras records one shoot as 2 separate frames. First overexposed, second underexposed